# Stream m3u with an embeded player on a website

Tags: jquery, html, m3u

I would like to know what are the best ways to stream m3u with an embeded player on a website nowdays thanks to HTML5 or Jquery. I would like to avoid flash.

I would also appreciate a tutorial to add this player on my website :

for the moment I have a http://78.xxx.xxx.xx:8000/listen.m3u and a html page.

Thanks a lot for you appreciated help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try this:

JQuery Playlist Plugin - Playlist support for audio and video tags.

HTML5 audio and video tags don't handle media playlists like m3u and others. This plugin is intended to provide a playlist parsing mechanism that will feed the audio/video tags with single media files they can handle. Limited navigation through the files included in the playlist is provided as well.

https://github.com/aitorciki/jquery-playlist